# Does the balanced python client library support authentication?

Tags: django, authentication, balanced-payments

I'm using django.

I've tried a lot of different things including urllib2, but I can't seem to create customers. I receive a 401 error.

If not how can I authenticate, and still use things like Customer().save()?

thanks
c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at https://github.com/balanced/balanced-django as an example to see how that library is doing it? I lack details as to if you're using the Balanced Python library (https://github.com/balanced/balanced-python) or something else. If you are using that library, make sure your API secret is making it down into something like balanced.configure which sets up the client library authentication. For example, `balanced.configure('ak-test-1kvvievk0Qqw5wQPsrlM9g7wQwNe62cyf')`.

Also, feel free to stop by #balanced on Freenode IRC if you'd like to get some help directly from Balanced developers who assist with integration.